Canvas App Return blank result after calling stored procedure
I am trying to retrieve data from the SQL stored procedure, but it returns a blank table, I have added the procedure connection.

I inserted a Gallery and I set the Item property: DPS.dboDPS({usr:77})
IF I tried to set it to: DPS.dboDPS({usr:77}).ResultSets.Table1, I got an error.
I set the arrow OnSelect property to : Set(myvar,DPS.dboDPS({usr:77}))
But the generated variable myvar is blank.

Note the same: issue when I try with Collection.
Below is my procedure:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DPS] 
@usr AS INT
AS 
Begin
select * from .Att.mydata
where UserID = @usr
End;
GO

I expect to retrieve data from SQL
